# What is the real risk of clicking a link?

Tags: http, exploit, phishing, ipsec, scam

If I were to click a link on any of my devices, be it over text message, email, or from a webpage, and enter no information/actions with the target page. What is the worst that could happen?

Comment: You cause the zombie apocalypse

Comment: This may be helpful: [Is there a real possibility of getting malware by “drive-by”?](/q/17852/129883)

Comment: What makes you think that the target of the link is a page?

Comment: Thank you @FireQuacker! That is very helpful.

Comment: @Chenmunka that is a good point, I guess it could be other things but possibly you would know by URL e.g. www.somewebsite.com/signup.html or something of the like

Comment: You've asked 2 different questions: the real risk, and the worst case. Those are different questions. And both very broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your browser (for example IE) contains a vulnerability such as [CVE-2020-0674](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-0674) then an attacker could gain access to your device via remote code execution or a number of other ways. Once they have gained access they could easily make your device part of a zombie network, install banking trojans, install ransomware etc.. etc... Best advice would be to use an up to date browser and not click any suspicious links. If you would like to investigate a link then I would recommend using a VM.

Answer (score -1):

The worst that could happen is your system downloads ransomware and subsequently infects all other devices on your network with ransomware. Or you are targeted with a banking trojan that steals your online banking credentials and subsequently your money.

Malware (especially ransomware) is not typically downloaded and run this way, [but drive-by downloads are definitely possible.](https://securityledger.com/2019/04/drive-by-malware-uses-google-sites-for-drive-by-download-attacks/)